# Two divs to define a range of min and max numbers

Tags: html, css

```css
#salary-range > div {
  display:inline;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=url],
input[type=number],
input[type=date],
input[type=password],
select, option,
textarea {
  width: 80%
}
```

```html
<div id="salary-range">
  <div>
    <span class="input"><label for="salary">Salary MIN</label><br>
      <input class='inp_cont' id="salary" name="salary" placeholder="Enter your salary" step="1000" min="0" required="" type="number">
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="input"><label for="salary">Salary MAX</label><br>
      <input class='inp_cont' id="salary" name="salary" placeholder="Enter your salary" step="1000" min="0" required="" type="number">
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get 'salary MIN' and 'salary MAX' to be side-by-side.
And the headings have to be always on top of the boxes.
And the total width of both boxes side-by-side should be 80%. 
And between the two boxes there should be something like 100px margin.
And how to make that the 'salary MAX' is never less than the 'salary MIN' that a user entered?

Answer (score 0):

Float your div left, and just give your input a margin right. See below:

```css
#salary-range > div {
  float: left;
}

.inp_cont {
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="salary-range">
  <div>
    <span class="input"><label for="salary">Salary MIN</label><br>
      <input class='inp_cont' id="salary" name="salary" placeholder="Enter your salary" step="1000" min="0" required="" type="number">
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="input"><label for="salary">Salary MAX</label><br>
      <input class='inp_cont' id="salary" name="salary" placeholder="Enter your salary" step="1000" min="0" required="" type="number">
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```